# asp.net label refresh

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I would like to get latest data from my db.
Right now my code works with auto refresh but i want to refresh the value each 1 sec.

js code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function updateLabel(){
  document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = Label1; 
  setTimeout("updateLabel()",1000);
  }
  updateLabel();
</script>
```

asp.net code:

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="LB"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = Label1;` - is there a javascript variable `Label1`?

Comment: Only label id = Label1

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way would be to use [Page Methods](http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.2) 
Of course you should consider the impact of making a request each second. If you have a lot of clients and the value updates rarely (say once every 30 seconds or less) you may consider using some push based technology like [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki) to be notified when the value changes instead of polling constantly. With 1 second interval it seems like using SignalR would make sense.